# "south-africa" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I propose the creation of a [south-africa](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-africa) tag. There are not many questions that target South Africa, but the few that do are sometimes tagged with [africa](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/africa), which is far too general. Examples of questions that will be improved with a [south-africa](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-africa) tag are:

- [Which authority regulates the conferring of degrees in South Africa?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/87138/27523)
- [What is the status/reputation of the University of South Africa (UNISA)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10728/27523)

Tags for specific countries already exist, e.g. [united-kingdom](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom), [germany](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany), etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I created it: [south-africa](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-africa).

I only found three questions that seemed to fit this tag, but if you find more you can certainly add them.